# Creating a List of items from a binding source

Tags: c#, database, list, data-binding, tableadapter

I have a binding source that is connected to a database. The binding source is connected to a data table that has 4 columns. Terms, Definitions, Store ID, and ID. I currently have a filter on Store ID so i can grab all the terms and definitions for the current store. Using this binding source i want to put terms in a List and the definitions in a list but I am not sure how to do this. I saw that in the currency manager there is a List method. What is the best way to do this?

*THE FILTER IS ON THE DEFINITION BINDING SOURCE*

I tried using table adapters but it is no filtering the store and here is the code i have tried:

```
        var definitionDataTable = definitionTableAdapter.GetData();
        var termArray = (from row in definitionDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                         select row.Field<string>("Term")).ToArray();
        var definitionArray = (from row in definitionDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                               select row.Field<string>("Description")).ToArray();
```

Any help is much appreciated, i am new to using databases just FYI.

Comment: The problem with that code is that the arrays contains all the definitions and terms for all the stores but i only want an arrays with one store (the current store). Does that makes sense?

Comment: var termArray = (from row in definitionDataTable.AsEnumerable() where row.Field<int>("StoreID")==yourID
                         select row.Field<string>("Term")).ToArray();

Comment: Thank you! Can you post as answer so i can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
var termArray = (from row in definitionDataTable.AsEnumerable() 
where row.Field<int>("StoreID")==yourID select row.Field<string>("Term")).ToArray();
```